# Zuul Forwarding error - Trying to connect to a different(unknown) ip

Tags: spring-boot, docker, routes, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have configured zuul proxy and eureka naming server for my spring boot application. Zuul proxy run on port `8765` and eureka runs on port `8761`.
Also two other microservices, **user-service** and **message-service** run on port `8081` and `8082`.

Also I have used swagger for the zuul proxy service where i can find all microservices api in one place.

**Swagger configuration in Zuul proxy service**

```
@Component
@Primary
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Controller implements SwaggerResourcesProvider{
    @Override
    public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
        List<SwaggerResource> resources= new ArrayList<>();
        SwaggerResource user = new SwaggerResource();
        user.setName("USER-SERVICE");
        user.setLocation("/api/user/v2/api-docs");
        user.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
        resources.add(user);
        SwaggerResource message = new SwaggerResource();
        message.setName("MESSAGE-SERVICE");
        message.setLocation("/api/message/v2/api-docs");
        message.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
        resources.add(message);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

**application.yml of Zuul proxy**

```
server:
  port: 8765

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-naming-server:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
    instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  routes:
    user-service:
      path: /user/**
      service-id: USER-SERVICE
    message-service:
      path: /message/**
      service-id: MESSAGE-SERVICE
```

Also i have used `docker-compose` file to up the docker microservices with default subnet (169.254.3.0/24).

**ip address of user-service** is 169.254.3.6
**ip address of message-service** is 169.254.3.10

**Here is the issue**

When I call these services via zuul proxy swgger ui, often i am getting **500 error**. That for the first time i hit the specific url it throws 500 error.
but after few attempt i get the response.

**Zuul log which indicate problem**

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
...
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.22.97.14:8081 [/172.22.97.14] failed: connect timed out
...
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.22.97.14:8081 [/172.22.97.14] failed: connect timed out
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

I have no idea about **172.22.97.14:8081**, why is not try to connect **172.22.97.14:8081** instead of connect to **169.254.3.6:8081**

Can someone help me to understand what is happening in here..

Any help would be grateful !

**[Edit]**
zuul proxy container ip is `169.254.3.10`

Comment: I think `169.254.3.6` is not raoutable in your case.can you connect to that address ?

Comment: @LinPy I can connect to 169.254.3.6 from the server. `telnet 169.254.3.6 8081` works fine.

Comment: I mean remotly not from where the IP local is

Comment: and where is the port `8081` defined in the config , I see the server try to connect to port `8084`

Comment: @LinPy Sorry. i have put wrong log. Anyway in port `8084` am running my admin-service same issue for that as well. I have edit the post.

Comment: @LinPy Do you have any idea about `172.22.97.14:8081`

Comment: @LinPy No. I can not `telnet 169.254.3.6 8081` from my machine. Please not that i have create a subent `169.254.3.0/24` and i used it in `docker-compose` file

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured on my project when I was using the same Zuulserver for developing microservices on localhost and DEV environment (when I started microservis on localhost it connected to zullserver on DEV env.). Then when I tried to call some operation through zuulserver it tried to connect to microservis not on DEV env. but on my machine.

I suspect the same problem on your side and IP on which you are developing your application is 172.22.97.14:8081.